# update approvers to jira incident via api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I want to raise jira incident with approvers using rest api. I am unable to do so as i am getting below error:

`customfield_XXXXX can not be set. it is not on the appropriate screen`

I assume I can not add approvers while creating incident. I am using curl to raise incident.
If I try to manually create an incident, I don't get any options to add approvers, but once jira is created, I can see the option to update approvers manually from web ui.

Is there a way I can update an already raised incident with the correct approver name?

The Jira version we are using is v8.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cannot add approvers when creating the issue is that the `approvers` field does not exists on the screen which assigned to the `create` context of the `screen scheme` which is assigned to the `incident` issue type in the project's `issue type screen scheme`.

You are probably able to add approvers once the issue is created either because the field exists on the screen assigned to the `edit` context of the screen scheme, or because you are setting it on a screen during a workflow transition.

If you have site administration permissions (or maybe just project administration permissions depending on how the site is configured), and it makes sense in the context of your use case, you could add the approvers field to the create screen.

To update the field after the issue has already been created, without making any config changes, is dependent on how you are currently able to set the field. You will either be able to make an API request to directly update the field, or you will need to transition the issue through whatever transition currently allows you to set the field, again via API.

Comment: Can you provide a example using curl to set the approver.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately that falls outside of my current knowledge. Try searching for something like "Edit Field Value Jira API" and hopefully you can find the answer

Comment: @RajnishKumarSoni, Apologies, I forgot to mention you in the previous comment

Comment: Thanks @tom for the ans. I was updating the wrong customfield. Its works now and i am able to update the approvers. Thank you foe the explanation.